# Calculate independent letter in a String

Tags: java

Write a program that, when given a string representing
a carpet, outputs its price.
Example: abacx
Answer: 20 (length 5 multiplied by 4 different types)

```
    int length = str.length();
    String letters = "";
    String str2 = " " + str;
    for (int i = 1; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            
        }
        if (str2.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i-1) ) {
            letters += str2.charAt(i);
            
        }
        
    }
    int length2 = letters.length();
    int price = length * length2;
    System.out.println(price);
```

Here's what I have so far.
These are the test cases
3a)qiraat
3b)cdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz
3c)warrior
3d)supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

Comment: Hint: you can compute the number of unique characters in a string by creating a `Set` containing the characters in the string, and then getting the size of the set.  Hint 2: how do you create that set?  Create an empty set, and add the characters to it, one at a time.

Comment: This is not a question, you are asking for someone to code something to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to multiply the number of characters the String contains by the unique number of characters it has.

The first one is trivial, it is simply `myString.length()`.

In order to get the second one, you can use a list of characters like this:

```java
    List<Character> uniqueChars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.lengt(); i ++) {
        char c = myString.charAt(i);
        if (!uniqueChars.contains(c)) {
            uniqueChars.add(c);
        }
    }

    int price = myString.length() * uniqueChars.size();
```

Comment: Use a `HashSet` rather than an `ArrayList`.